# What is the right format to store datetime for Pig and Hive?

Tags: datetime, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

While using Pig for ETL, I'm putting processed data in Hive using the HCatStorer:

```
STORE dataprocessed INTO 'database.table' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

My goal is to make the data of the destination table usable either from Pig or from Hive (depending on the skills of the user)

What is the recommended format to store datetime?

I care of:

- Storing timezone info
- Being able to compare dates
- Being human readable (as an example, I don't believe timestamp are human readable)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably store date/time related information as ISO-8601 formatted strings/chararrays as HCatStorer does not support Date types (at least in pig) directly.

There are functions to convert date/time information in pig: http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.13.0/func.html#datetime-functions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel bad at storing date as string: it's hard to sync with all people in a company to use the same format. My understanding is that there's no way to store date as an object. Is that correct?

Comment: As far as I know that is correct as far as pig is concerned. This page contains all data types supported by HCatStorage, DateTime is not amongst them: https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/hcat-r0.5.0/loadstore.html (see "HCatalog Data Types")

Comment: Yes, it's what I thought. That's kind of sad because it makes datetimes more complex to manage :(. Thanks a lot for your help.